# Creating a second android navigation bar inside a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigationbar

i'm trying to create another navigation bar (top navigation bar) inside a fragment that already have bottom navigation bar. but i only find a way to do it (based on searching the android docs and sites) on a new activity not on a fragment that already had bottom navigation bar. Those 4 menus are fragment (Home, History, Message and profile)

edit : i already found kotlin solution (https://medium.com/@avinriyan/android-kotlin-bottom-navigation-tab-layout-19d062256882) sadly i'm using java and knows java only

[image: prototype]

it should look like above link (image)

i tried to browse a way to do it but i can't find a single tutorial either on youtube nor google.

[image: template]

i already have bottom navigation view like shown on above link (image)

i'm a complete beginner i need this for my project. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TabLayout` for that purpose. Here is an article about it [on medium](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-material-design-tabs-tab-layout-with-swipe-884085ae80ff)

Or you can use libraries with custom views that also implement such feature. For example [DViews](https://github.com/Dsyncer/DViews) that has `TopMenuView`  which is easy-to-use analog of `TabLayout`
[Screenshot of TopMenuView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y7Ql.jpg)